# How to make map.find() function with a std::pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, std-pair

I'm getting this error trying to do map.find(10,20) does anyonw knows how to do it

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, 
_Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [with _Kty=std::pair<int, int>, _Ty=std::tuple<int, int, int>, _Pr=std::less<std::pair<int, int>>, 
_Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int, int>>>]" matches the argument list  Maps
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>,std::tuple<int,int,int>> myMap;
    // Inserting data in std::map
    myMap[std::make_pair(10, 20)] = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);

    auto it = myMap.cbegin();
    for (auto const& it : myMap){ 
        std::cout << it.first.first << it.first.second << std::get<0>(it.second); 

    }


    auto search = myMap.find(10,20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `find({10,20})`.

Comment: Did you look at the signature of [`map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)? None of the overloads take 2 arguments. `myMap.find({10,20});` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `std::pair` as a key, not two `int`s. When you inserted the item, you correctly used `std::make_pair`. You'll need to do the same with the `find` member function or, as mentioned in the comments, wrap your key in braces. Both do the same thing; the first is more explicit, in the second case you're relying on implicit conversion to `std::pair`.

```
auto search = myMap.find(std::make_pair(10, 20));
```

or

```
auto search = myMap.find({10, 20});
```